# websocket rails pushing using channel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, websocket, push

I am trying to use a pushing mechanism using websocket-rails gem in ROR application.

I have basically done the folowing.

my application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require websocket_rails/main

$(function(){

  // connect to server like normal
  var dispatcher = new WebSocketRails('localhost:3000/websocket');

  // subscribe to the channel
  var channel = dispatcher.subscribe('products');

  // bind to a channel event
  channel.bind('new', function(data) {
    console.log('channel event received: ' + data);
  });
});
```

then I started thin server at port 3000

Then I from rails console, I entered the following command.

```
WebsocketRails[:products].trigger(:new, Product.last)
```

But nothing was printed in browser console.

Have I missed some setup configuration?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came across this too. The [documentation](http://websocket-rails.github.io) says:

*Broadcast to the channel from anywhere inside your Rails application. An existing controller, a model, a background job, or a new WebsocketRails controller.*

i.e. no mention of the console.

In my experience, it works exactly as described fine from the controller though.

Comment: It is true, I have the same problem and it works fine when I put the code in a controller.

Comment: cant I use it on a model?

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is quite old, but there is some update on the project, so for everyone coming here in the future, now using [Synchronization](https://github.com/websocket-rails/websocket-rails/wiki/Multiple-Servers-and-Background-Jobs) between instances events can be triggered from everywhere, even from rails console.

Add this to your `config/initializers/websocket_rails.rb`

```
WebsocketRails.setup do |config|
  config.synchronize = true
end
```